# Add X pixels to current position CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So, I'm trying to recreate a .gif I found online in pure CSS. However, I've run into a problem when creating the animation-part of this.
Here's the GIF I'm trying to recreate:
[image]

As you can see, the source image breaks up in:

1. 3 walls
2. 9 columns
3. 27 cubes

And then returning by changing to 9 rows, 3 flats and a cube again.

I've measured everything in pixels and everything fits in the completely "exploded" state, but I can't seem to figure out how to animate it properly.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hazqvmh7/) you can see I've managed to get to the 9 columns. However, when I try to animate to the 27 cubes (changing from styling columns to single cubes), I apply margin that also affect the cubes in the "columns-stage". See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4c53guuk/1/)

> Note: Hover over the `test area` to trigger the animation!

Is there a way I can stage the margin (all the `margin-top`s from `line 125`) to occur on the moment they do in the 2nd fiddle, but not influence the blocks before the 2 second delay is actually taking place? I was thinking of saying `margin-top` should get `X + 30px` or something, but I can't seem to find something like that for CSS. Do I have to resort to jQuery? (I wanted to test how far I could get with CSS, so rather not!)

This is one of those pieces where a block is only getting its `margin-top` changed, the rest of the CSS and HTML can be found in the Fiddles (it is simply too much to copy/paste everything here):

```
#test-area:hover + #cube .block111, #test-area:hover + #cube .block121, #test-area:hover + #cube .block131 {
    margin-top: -30px;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't from [Seif Shawkat's codepen?](http://codepen.io/shawkat/pen/KwENOE)

Comment: Haha cool, didn't know there were multiple people trying to achieve it :) No, I can promise you I've built everything by myself up until I posted my question here. Thanks for the link though! Also, if you're wondering: the original comes from a Dutch graphics designer: http://flrn.nl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

The issue is you're basically just overriding your styles with ones from line 125 and on. You can remove the transitions and you'll understand what's happening: You set most blocks' `margin-top` on line 116 as `28px` then override them on line 126 with `-30px`. Since this is later on the stylesheet, it takes precedence, therefore ignoring the earlier ones  altogether. Take note that transition-delay isn't supposed work like frames. You can use @keyframes for that.

**The solution (sort of)**

Use other properties to style the blocks for the third action. I edited your fiddle and used `top` and `left` properties to move the second action and left the margin-top intact to do the third ones (with the values adjusted a bit.)

Set the `div[class^="row"]`s to relative so you can use absolute positioning. That's pretty much it. I made a fiddle but you probably want to solve it yourself. I'll leave it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k6acvpfb/1/) nonetheless.

**Optional Note**

In the fiddle, I changed some bits while trying things out. You can add some column class to your blocks to reduce the selectors on line 115 and line 120. In your classes, all `.block` that end in 1 are `.col1`. That way, that big line on line 115 is reduced to

```
#test-area:hover + #cube .col1{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Going to play with this solution. Since I need to add even more movement, I have to come up with a better solution than this, but thanks!

Comment: Felt I should update you, since you wrote such a good answer. Since I couldn't fix it with just applying different `margin`s or positions (simply too many steps in the original gif), I had to resort to the `@keyframes` you mentioned. Thanks for the help, the result can be found here: http://rvervuurt.com/cube